# .htaccess not working after upgrading to php 8

Tags: catalina, apache, php

Mac OS Catalina. I was using Apache with the default PHP shipped with the OS (7.3.11).
I installed PHP 8 using Homebrew, replaced the PHP module in httpd.conf, and added the following code:

```
<IfModule php_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

After restarting Apache, .htaccess files stopped working (ignored)

Comment: If you roll back the changes you've made and restart Apache again, does `.htaccess` get considered again? Can you run `diff old-conf new-conf` to check whether you changed some other stuff by accident?

Comment: @nohillside, yes. I'm able to change the version back and everything works just fine. 
Additionally, I discovered mismatching PHP versions in php-fpm. It still uses 7.3. I suppose that's what causes the problem. Don't know what's the solution though